# Stop Changes to Maintenance Plan from Renaming Linked SQL Agent Job

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, jobs, maintenance-plans

Is there a way to stop a SQL job (which calls a maintenance plan) from being renamed every time i open and save that maintenance plan?
Each time i do that, a prefix of "_SubPlan" gets added to the name of the job - even after i've removed it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can overcome the problem stopping using native maintenace plans and instead you could use ola hallengren maintenance solution

https://ola.hallengren.com/